# Pegar URL do projeto

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf

Olá, preciso pegar a url de onde se encontra o meu projeto (wpf). O motivo é o seguinte: nele há um upload de imagem para dentro da pasta Imagem (que está na solution do meu projeto) e preciso da urla do mesmo para que a imagem seja salva na pasta correta. Eu poderia colocar manualmente, mas toda vez que mudar de computador, eu teria que alterar e isso não é muito viável.

Comment: Você pode usar `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Comment: @qmechanik show. Valeu

Comment: Postei como resposta. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma seria usar o [`System.AppDomain.BaseDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) para encontrar arquivos ou diretórios que estejam no mesmo diretório do projeto.

Uma outra forma seria usar o [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx), mas não é recomendado, pois o valor poderá mudar durante a execução do programa.